# How to share protobuf files between maven modules?

Tags: java, maven, protocol-buffers, grpc-java

I have two services A and B which placed in monorepo in different maven modules, also they have Aggregate `pom.xml` which contains the next modules:

```xml
<modules>
    <module>A</module>
    <module>B</module>
</modules>
```

Both services are talking through gRPC and have common protocol which described in the proto files.
The [grpc-java manual](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java) says, that I must put my proto files into `src/main/resourses/proto` folder.
It means I have to copy the same proto files bewteen two services:

1. `A/src/main/resourses/proto/somefile.proto`
2. `B/src/main/resourses/proto/somefile.proto`

Which is code duplication actually.
The main question - How can I share and compile proto files between two maven modules in monorepo?

I have done the next:

1. Created the separate library which contains only proto files. Let's call it C.
2. Added C dependency to A and B modules.
   Aggregated `pom.xml` looks like:

```xml
<modules>
    <module>C</module>
    <module>A</module>
    <module>B</module>
</modules>
```

The approach seems quite havy for that case and I don't want to have a separate maven module for that.
Moreover, I will definetley face with a problem, if I use different language for B service (something other than java and maven).
Is there a known solution for this problem? Can I share protofiles without separate library/module? Any examples appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I've been wrong with

> The grpc-java manual says, that I must put my proto files into
> src/main/resourses/proto folder.

We can set `protoSourceRoot` configuration for [grpc-java](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java) plugin. We can specify any required proto source folder as follows:

```xml
<protoSourceRoot>${basedir}/../proto</protoSourceRoot>
```

It means no need in separate `maven` module and library.